# New and learning, Need help cleaning this up

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm completely new to SQL and have been reading and learning a lot from this forum. I've written the following query and it seems like its close, can anyone help?

Inc_main
occup_id  type  completed   staff_id
000001     200  22-Jan-09   MCGI01
000001     200  27-Feb-09   MCGI01
000003     200  30-Dec-08   CRIT01

Occ_main
occup_id    name    insp_dist   zone    number  street  st_type
000003  Business Name   62  1   10945   street name RD
000004  Business Name   61  2   9730    street name RD
000005  Business Name   62  1   10965   street name RD

```
SELECT 
  occ_main.insp_dist, Ins_main.Occup_id, Ins_main.Completed, Ins_main.Type, Ins_main.staff_id,DATEDIFF  (Day,Ins_main.completed,GETDATE())AS diffdate
FROM
  Occ_main INNER JOIN Ins_main.occup_id ON Occ_main.occup_id = Ins_main.occup_id INNER JOIN
  Ins_main INNER JOIN(SELECT ins_main.Occup_id, MAX(ins_main.Completed) as maxdate
    FROM Ins_main
    group by ins_main.Occup_id) c2
    ON c2.Occup_id = Ins_main.Occup_id
    and c2.maxdate = Ins_main.Completed


GROUP BY
  occ_main.insp_dist,
  Ins_main.occup_id,
  Ins_main.completed,
  Ins_main.type,
  Ins_main.staff_id
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'its close'? Also, you should add the table definition of your base to your message

Comment: Close to what; are you having specific problems with it?

Comment: The query will run without the Occ_main table and fields. Now i receive the following error;  TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Report Builde

An error occurred while executing the query.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 156)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join is a little messed up. Try this:

```
SELECT 
  occ_main.insp_dist, Ins_main.Occup_id, Ins_main.Completed, Ins_main.Type, Ins_main.staff_id, 
  DATEDIFF(Day,Ins_main.completed, GETDATE()) AS diffdate
FROM
  Occ_main INNER JOIN Ins_main 
  ON Occ_main.occup_id = Ins_main.occup_id 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT ins_main.Occup_id, MAX(ins_main.Completed) as maxdate
    FROM Ins_main
    group by ins_main.Occup_id) c2
    ON c2.Occup_id = Ins_main.Occup_id
    and c2.maxdate = Ins_main.Completed 
GROUP BY
  occ_main.insp_dist,
  Ins_main.occup_id,
  Ins_main.completed,
  Ins_main.type,
  Ins_main.staff_id
```